# How to keep past value after error in html?

Tags: html, flask-wtforms

I have a textarea form and want to keep the value that the user has inserted if an error occurs when trying to submit. I've tried what works with input type="text", but when I use textarea the past value of the field is gone when an error occurs. All other questions related to this are for PHP apps, anyone know what to do when its HTML?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="msg">Message:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <textarea type="text" rows="3" class="form-control" name="message" value="{{request.form.msg}}" id="msg" required></textarea>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In a non SPA applications its difficult. You could pass it as a GET request and check on the page if GET request value is available or not

Comment: Dammit, was hoping for a simple solution. Thank you for your quick response.

Comment: Just so I'm clear, you're trying to keep what the user entered in the textarea, right? So if they entered ABC123 and then the submission failed, when they came back to the page, they would see ABC123?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fixed it! Simply by putting {{request.form.msg}} in between , like this:

```
<textarea type="text" rows="3" class="form-control" name="message" id="msg" required>{{request.form.msg}}</textarea>
```